# rundeck - How can I get project.properties file

Tags: centos7, job-scheduling, rundeck

I installed rundeck at centos7 and create project sample_project.
next Im tring to add node. rundeck documentation say project.properties file genelated when create project.

> One of these is generated at project setup time. Each project has a directory within the Rundeck projects directory, and the config file is within the etc subdirectory:

```
$RDECK_BASE/projects/[PROJECT-NAME]/etc/project.properties
```

But I could not find.  How would I be able to get it?

environment
 ・rundeck3.1 via yum
 ・centos7.6

Answer (score 0):

Using YUM based installation at: /var/rundeck/projects/your-project/etc/project.properties

You have more information here:

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/configuration.html#filesystem

Comment: Thanks. I checked documentation and found the answer. I needed to set [Edit Node] from GUI.After that, I finally found project.properties file.